# Probability of selecting a non-measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

If you randomly select a subset of $[0,1]$, what is the probability that it will be measurable?

Edit: This question may be unanswerable as asked.  If additional assumptions could be made to make it answerable, I would be interested in learning about them.

Comment: Or is this even a valid question as currently phrased?

Comment: That's like asking what's the measure of all non-measurable sets...

Comment: It is!  Has that question been answered?

Comment: How would you measure a non-measurable set? As first commenter pointed out, need to think about how to phrase/well-define this.

Comment: Well, I'm not asking how to measure the nonmeasurable subsets of $[0,1]$ themselves.  I'm asking how to measure a specific subset of $2^{[0,1]}$ consisting of only these objects.

Comment: What's your process for randomly selecting a subset of $[0,1]$? That is, what is your measure on $2^{[0,1]}$?

Comment: I guess that is the underlying question.  Is there no canonical way to do this?

Comment: There is a somewhat canonical way, using the Kolmogorov extension theorem, to get a $\{0,1\}$-valued stochastic process $X_t$ on $[0,1]$, such that its finite-dimensional distributions are equidistributed. These correspond to subsets of $U \subseteq [0,1]$, via $x\in U$ iff $X_t = 1$. I am not sure what the answer to the question for this construction is.

Comment: TBH, I am fairly interested in this. I have been thinking about this: We know that the set $A\subset Pot([0,1])$ of all measurable sets is (truly) larger than $\mathbb{R}$, iow., there is no injection from A to $\mathbb{R}$. Using the continuum hypothesis, we know that there must exist a bijection between A and $Pot([0,1])\setminus A$, wich, in turn, proves there must exist a limit $\in(0,1)$ to this probability? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @CBenni you're mistaken on a few fronts; firstly, in invoking the notion of 'limit' when you haven't even defined what a limit would be with respect to, and secondly in assuming that any such would be in (0,1) simply because both sides are 'equinumerous'.  Consider e.g. $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{n^2:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Measurable in what sense? Borel? Lebesgue? Counting measure? Are you assuming the axiom of choice?

Comment: @CBenni: What does CH have to do with subsets of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki true... I didnt think about that. I would still be interested in the answer to this question ;)
I am not sure, but I think I read that Borel proved that almost all (all but for a null set) subsets of (0,1) are non-measurable. Therefore, we would have the probability 1.

Comment: @orlandpm http://mathoverflow.net/questions/102386/is-a-random-subset-of-the-real-numbers-non-measurable-is-the-set-of-measurable

Comment: @CBenni: I think you could post this as an answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge not so sure. But I will go for it ^.^

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following topological smallness (rather than measure smallness) result may be of interest.

Let ${\mathbb P}[0,1]$ be the collection of all subsets of $[0,1]$ modulo the equivalence relation $\sim$ defined by $E \sim F \Leftrightarrow {\lambda^{*}(E \Delta F)} = 0,$ where $\lambda^{*}$ is Lebesgue outer measure and $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference operation on sets. The set ${\mathbb P}[0,1]$ can be made into a complete metric space by defining the distance function $d,$ where $d(E,F) = {\lambda^{*} (E \Delta F)}.$ In the paper cited below it is proved that the collection of measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ is a perfect nowhere dense set in ${\mathbb P}[0,1].$

Thus, in this setting, the collection of measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ makes up a *very tiny part* of the collection of all the subsets of $[0,1].$ Note that in the space ${\mathbb P}[0,1]$ the collection of measurable subsets is not just a first category subset of ${\mathbb P}[0,1]$ (this alone would make the collection a *tiny* subset of ${\mathbb P}[0,1]$), but in fact the collection of measurable subsets is actually a nowhere dense subset of ${\mathbb P}[0,1]$ (hence my saying the collection is a *very tiny* subset of ${\mathbb P}[0,1]$).

Nobuyuki Kato, Tadashi Kanzo, and Oharu Shinnosuke, *A note on the measure problem*, **International Journal of Mathematical Education in Science and Technology** 19 (1988), 315-318.

Comment: Is it possible to give a free link to the paper that's cited in your answer. I found [this link](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/epdf/10.1080/0020739880190210?needAccess=true); however, I'm not involved with any university and I can't get it for free, plus my caretaker isn't willing to spend 56 dollars. Hopefully you have a copy that you could share in your answer.

Comment: @Davis Johnson: I don't have online access to this journal (in fact, none except MAA journals via my MAA membership), but I do have a photocopy of the paper (made many years ago in a university library) that I can .pdf-scan and email to you. [Send me an email for me to reply.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13130/dave-l-renfro?tab=profile)

Comment: @Davis Johnson: Yes, but delete your comment, as I don't want to wind up getting hundreds of spam emails if my email gets harvested somewhere.

Comment: Deleted the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Almost the same Question was asked on mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102386/is-a-random-subset-of-the-real-numbers-non-measurable-is-the-set-of-measurable

The conclusion was that the set of all measurable sets was not measurable; Therefore, no Probability can be provided.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that we have fixed some $\sigma$-field of subsets of the interval and "measureable" subset means a subset from that $\sigma$-field.

Your question is meaningless until we specify what does "randomly select a subset" mean. And to do that we have to choose a $\sigma$-field of subsets of the set $2^{[0,1]}$, say $\mathcal{A}$, and a probability measure $\mathbb{P}:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow [0,1]$. It is easy to see that now when we know what does "randomly select a subset" mean we can answer your question. And what is the answer? Depending on the choice of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ it can be any number between $0$ and $1$, and none of those answers is better than the other. (From the point of view of probability theory)