# Is it true the set of Lebesgue-measurable functions which are non-integrable are prevalent in the set of measurable functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions

Suppose $A$ is an arbitrary set in Caratheodory extension, where $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f$ is an arbitrary, lebesgue measurable function where $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$

According to [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/28114/87856) and [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-03/S0273-0979-05-01060-8/S0273-0979-05-01060-8.pdf), “almost all” measurable functions in a function space can be defined without a measure on the set of measurable functions. Such a set of functions are known as *[prevelant set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prevalent_and_shy_sets)* in a function space.

According to my hypothesis, the set of Lebesgue-measurable functions that are non-integrable are prevelant in the set of measurable functions.

One statistician, of whom I messaged, stated the following:

> We follow the argument presented in example 3.6 of [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-03/S0273-0979-05-01060-8/S0273-0979-05-01060-8.pdf),
> take $X:=L^{0}(A)$ (measurable functions over $A$), let $P$ denote the
> one-dimensional sub-space of $A$ consisting of constant functions
> (assuming the Lebesgue measure on $A$) and let $F:=L^{0}(A)\setminus
>  L^{1}(A)$ (measurable functions over $A$ with no finite integral).
>
> Let $\lambda_{P}$ denotes the Lebesgue measure over $P$, for any fixed
> $f\in F$:
>
> $$\lambda_{P}\left(\left\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\left| \int_{A}\left(f+\alpha\right) d\mu<\infty\right.\right\}\right)=0 $$
> Meaning $P$ is a one-dimensional probe of $f$, so $f$ is a 1-prevalent set.

Is this correct? Does this prove my hypothesis? For what other notions of “size” (provided in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4622127/proof-that-neither-almost-none-nor-almost-all-functions-which-are-lebesgue-m)) are “almost all” Lebesgue-measurable function non-integrable?

As a final note, here is my (informal) attempt to answer this question:

> Note that almost all functions can be desribed as a set of
> pseudo-random points that are non-uniformly distributed in a sub-space
> of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. (To visualize, see
> [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4625345/1142990)).
>
> Now assume we have that same function but it is defined on a lebesgue
> measurable set (e.g. defined on  $[0,1]$). If we partition the
> functions’ domain, the subset of points in that function may have
> the largest pre-image in a partition that is non-Lebesgue measurable,
> making the function non-integrable. The chance that a random set is
> Lebesgue measurable is extremely small (see [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4209391/1142990)).
> Therefore, using the previous paragraph, "almost all" functions or
> "most" functions are non-integrable

Comment: I'm not able to answer your question, but shouldn't your LaTeX code rather be `\lambda_{P}\left(\left\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\left|
\int_{A}\left(f+\alpha\right); d\mu<\infty\right.\right\}\right)=0`?

Comment: @jpboucheron oops, my bad. There’s a glitch in the system that forces me to add another slash. I’m not why it all the sudden ended.