# Is it true the set of functions with an infinite or undefined expected value form a prevalent subset of the set of all functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions

Suppose for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ which is measurable w.r.t to <s>to some arbitrary measure</s> the [radon-nikodym derivative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) of the uniform probability measure on the $\sigma$-algebra of caratheodory measurable sets <s>along</s> with measurable function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$.

According to [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/28114/87856) and [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-03/S0273-0979-05-01060-8/S0273-0979-05-01060-8.pdf), “almost all” measurable functions in a function space can be defined without a measure on the set of measurable functions. Such a set of functions are known as *[prevelant set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prevalent_and_shy_sets)* in a function space.

**Question:** Is it true the set of all functions with infinite or undefined expected value forms a prevalent <s>set in the</s> subset of the set of all measurable and non-measurable functions?

This is a sequel to question, "[Is it true the set of Lebesgue-measurable functions that are non-integrable are prevalent in the set of measurable functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4625438/1142990)" I assume if the question in that link can be answered then the question here could be answered. (Infact, a statisticians' answer in that link was *only part of the full answer stated here*):

> We can follow the argument presented in example 3.6 of [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-03/S0273-0979-05-01060-8/S0273-0979-05-01060-8.pdf)
>
> Because a function can always be represented as $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$ we only consider whether positive functions have a mean value. We consider the case of set $A$ with a finite positive measure. In this context having a mean means having a finite integral, and not not being integrable means having an infinite integral.
>
> Take $X:=L^{0}(A)$ (measurable functions over $A$), let $P$ denote the
> one-dimensional sub-space of $A$ consisting of constant functions
> (assuming the Lebesgue measure on $A$) and let $F:=L^{0}(A)\setminus
>  L^{1}(A)$ (measurable functions over $A$ with no finite integral).
>
> Let $\lambda_{P}$ denotes the Lebesgue measure over $P$, for any fixed
> $f\in F$:
>
> $$\lambda_{P}\left(\left\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\left| \int_{A}\left(f+\alpha\right) d\mu<\infty\right.\right\}\right)=0 $$
> Meaning $P$ is a one-dimensional probe of $f$, so $f$ is a 1-prevalent set.

Is this true?

<s>If so, then it seems my hypothesis is incorrect. Is this true?</s>

If so, this still does not completely prove my hypothesis since we are taking the subset of all Lebesgue-measurable functions rather than the *<s>set</s> subset of all measurable and non-measurable functions*.

What do you think and what are your suggestions to proving <s>this</s> my hypothesis?

<s>since measurable functions with a undefined expected value is prevelant in the set of all measurable functions; and the expected value of functions defined on non-measurable sets have an undefined expected value, the set of all functions (measurable/non-measurable) with an undefined (or infinite) expected value should be prevelant in the set of all functions</s> .

Comment: When you say $f$ has undefined expected value, do you mean $f$ is measurable but not integrable, or is $f$ allowed to be non-measurable?

Comment: @Adam Both: $f$ is measurable but not integrable and $f$ is allowed to be non-measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I'll assume the existence of non-measurable subsets of $A$ here, since otherwise all functions $f:A \to \mathbb R$ are measurable, and the question reduces to your previous one.

Let $X \subset A$ be non-measurable, and pick any function $f:A \to \mathbb R$. We will consider the one-dimensional vector space

$$V = \{f + c1_X : c \in \mathbb R\}.$$

Suppose two functions $g, h \in V$ are measurable. Then the function $$h - g = c1_X,\quad c \in \mathbb R,$$ is measurable, so $c = 0$, and $g = h$. Thus $V$ contains at most one measurable function, and we may deduce that the non-measurable functions are a prevalent set.